# Oozie sharlib unavailability issue

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, oozie

Due to re-sizing cluster many times I get org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException exception for few jars under /user/oozie/share/lib/ path and it corrupts lib location then I need to create sharelib again every time. IS it possible if I don't get jar under /user/oozie/share/lib/ path on hdfs then I can copy same jar from s3 location to hdfs? Is it possible  to configure alternate path for oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath? That alternate path is s3 location.

Comment: did you try fix the missing error with command : hadoop dfsck

Comment: hadoop fsck /user/oozie/share/lib/ -files -blocks -racks this will identify corrupt or missing blocks. There is no way to recover those blocks once they are missing. So I found two approaches: 1. If jar is not found on hdfs then go for s3 location where jars will be available always. But I dont know how to achieve this. 2. If possible each datanode should copy their data to live nodes before termination for maintaining replica.

Comment: You can change the `fs.defaultFS` to point to an S3 bucket in your `core-site.xml`